# JavaScript QuerySelector not returning last child

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select the last child element of the class .nav-item and I've tried it several ways. It doesn't grab the item and just returns 'null' and applying styles will either grab the first item or return the following error:

**main.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at main.js:25**

My code :

The top part works fine and does apply the border, but I want to apply a border on the right of the last item and a border on the left of the first item. The last item is not working.

Can anyone point out my mistake? 
The HTML if that helps:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].style.borderTop = '0.2em solid white';
  items[i].style.borderBottom = '0.2em solid white';
}

// First and Last Item
// var secondItem = document.querySelector('.list-group-item:nth-child(2)');
// secondItem.style.color = 'coral';

let lastItem = document.querySelector('.nav-item:nth-child(4)');

console.log(lastItem);

lastItem.style.borderRight = '0.2em solid white';
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Item Lister</h1>
  <ul class="nav" id="list">
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: First of all, `ul` should only contains `li` as direct children. Second, each `li` is currently the first child of an anchor.

Comment: Move the anchor inside `li` like this: `<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the options lastElementChild and firstElementChild. These worked.

Answer (score 3):

So your `<nav>` element has one child: the `<ul>`. The `<a>` elements are children of the `<ul>`.

To fix this, you would need to querySelect `.nav-item ul:nth-child(4)`.

Here's something to visualize it a little better. The `<nav>` is the parent to the `<ul>`, who is the parent to the `<a>`s. That makes `<nav>` the grandparent to the `<a>`s.

```
nav
  ul
    a
      li
    a
      li
    a
      li
    a
      li
```

Also important like Karl-André Gagnon said to make sure the `<li>` is a child of the `<ul>`:

```
nav
  ul
    li
      a
    li
      a
    li
      a
    li
      a
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using document.querySelectorAll

1. Get all elements of class - nav-item irrespective parent and child relation
2. Convert HTML collection into Array using Array.from
3. Using pop() method get the last element to style

   `let lastItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')).pop();`

Sample working code for reference

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].style.borderTop = '0.2em solid white';
  items[i].style.borderBottom = '0.2em solid white';
}

// First and Last Item
// var secondItem = document.querySelector('.list-group-item:nth-child(2)');
// secondItem.style.color = 'coral';

let lastItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')).pop();

console.log(lastItem);

lastItem.style.borderRight = '0.2em solid black';
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Item Lister</h1>
  <ul class="nav" id="list">
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="nav-item">One</li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jOOvVjq

**Issue:**:
 :nth-child works with sibling elements, so :nth-child(4) is not available

**As per MDN**

---

The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

Answer (score -2):

Please change .nav-item to a. It serves your purpose as a is the child element of parent ul not the .nav-item.

```
let lastItem = document.querySelector('a:nth-child(4)');
```

It worked for me. Let me know if it is working for you.